# Sencha Touch Kitchensink app "clone" - model not found

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch-2

I have tried to clone the Speakers example from the *Kitchen Sink -Sencha* App into my own app.
I copied the model (`Speaker.js`), store (`Speakers.js`), view (`BasicDataView.js`), feed (`feed.js`)
and changed the name of the first element of the class path from *Kitchen Sink* to *MyFirstApp*.

my `app.js` looks as follows:

```
Ext.Loader.setConfig({
    enabled: true
});

Ext.application({
    name: 'MyFirstApp',

    controllers: ['Main'],
    //loads app/store/Demos.js, which contains the tree data for our main navigation NestedList
    stores: ['Speakers'],

    launch: function() {
       Ext.create('MyFirstApp.store.Speakers', { id: 'Speakers' });
       MyFirstApp.util.Proxy.process('feed.js');    
           Ext.create('MyFirstApp.view.Viewport');
       }
    });
```

However, the App won't start. My Chromium debugger tells me the following:

```
Uncaught Error: [ERROR][Ext.data.Store#setModel] Model with name "MyFirstApp.model.Speaker" does not exist. Console.js?_dc=1395265484974:17
Ext.define.doWrite Console.js?_dc=1395265484974:17
Ext.define.write Writer.js?_dc=1395265484999:49
Ext.define.log Logger.js?_dc=1395265484923:132
(anonymous function) Logger.js?_dc=1395265484923:150
Ext.define.applyModel Store.js?_dc=1395265486959:901
Ext.apply.generateSetter.setter sencha-touch.js:5544
Base.implement.initConfig sencha-touch.js:4982
Ext.define.constructor Store.js?_dc=1395265486959:833
Ext.apply.create.Class sencha-touch.js:5270
(anonymous function)
Ext.ClassManager.instantiate sencha-touch.js:7011
Ext.apply.factory sencha-touch.js:10120
Ext.define.instantiateStores Application.js?_dc=1395265486668:770
Ext.define.onDependenciesLoaded Application.js?_dc=1395265486668:685
Ext.apply.refreshQueue sencha-touch.js:8260
Ext.apply.refreshQueue sencha-touch.js:8261
Ext.apply.refreshQueue sencha-touch.js:8261
Ext.apply.refreshQueue sencha-touch.js:8261
Ext.apply.refreshQueue sencha-touch.js:8261
Ext.apply.refreshQueue sencha-touch.js:8261
Ext.apply.onFileLoaded sencha-touch.js:8589
(anonymous function) sencha-touch.js:3270
Ext.apply.injectScriptElement.onLoadFn
```

What might possibly have gone wrong? I guess I tried comparing the *Kitchen Sink* app with
my app dozens of times and don't see differences, apart from the contents of `bootstrap.js`.

The whole code of the app is [here](http://1drv.ms/OBJfKb).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the code lacks declaration of the model in app.js. Not exactly sure why but that fixes the problem.

Answer (score 3):

My suggestion is first you follow any Sencha tutorial. I am listing some og your mistakes:

1. You have not added `models` and `views` in app.js file.
2. Your shared app's code is not having Viewport.js and also store and model files are missing.

Comment: yes, of course, you are right. I haven't prepared the archive file properly. will correct it this evening